# Getting error "declaration does not declare anything" on typedef

Tags: c++

I am getting this error when I am trying to build my code. The error is coming in a line where there is a type_def. How to get around this error ?

```
typedef long            sbsize_t;
typedef unsigned long   bsize_t;
```

Please help me out.

Comment: What is the error????????????

Comment: Please add a http://sscce.org/

Comment: It's no good asking us to diagnose an error if you dont show us the error..!

Answer (score 3):

g++4.8 generates this error in such case:

```
#define sbsize_t
#define bsize_t
typedef long            sbsize_t;
typedef unsigned long   bsize_t;


main.cpp:15:9: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 typedef long            sbsize_t;
         ^
main.cpp:16:18: error: declaration does not declare anything [-fpermissive]
 typedef unsigned long   bsize_t;
```

so maybe you have such defines somewhere in your code?